# Can't open another activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

when i am attempting to press the button to open a another activity 
first click it looks,

```
02-03 20:48:42.489 17665-17665/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-03 20:48:42.579 17665-17665/? I/PGA: Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 17665, tid = 17665
02-03 20:48:42.619 17665-17665/? I/PGA: New SOCKET connection: com.example.balamasthang.smartattendance (pid 17665, tid 17665)
02-03 20:48:42.619 17665-17665/? W/PGA: [17665] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x4a8937a0, 0x0, 0x7989bc88, 0x77603be0)
02-03 20:48:42.619 17665-17665/? W/PGA: [17665] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x4a8937a0, 0x0, 0x7989bc88, 0x77603be0) returned
02-03 20:48:42.629 17665-17665/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

**When i was clicking second time it looks**

something like java.lang ..... error in red color. . but only visible 1 seconds. and it was gone. . and looks like a first click in logcat.
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I think you could add some additional detail.  Is this your program?  If so, include some of the relevant code.  If not your code, then provide some additional details about what that is.

Answer (score 0):

> You should define activity in android manifest. Can you forget it ?